# Converting inconsistent data to DateTime

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, visual-studio-2012

I have to read a file, and loop through each line and inject it to database, but the problem is when I split each row with `,` one of its index contains date string with inconsistent format.

Sometime it starts with year `2014-01-01`, and sometime it starts with day `01-01-2014`.
The problem is my database field type is datetime, I can't fix the data, because it's 4000 lines data, is there is a way to convert it?

```
foreach (string line in lines)
{
    var txt = line.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    idx += 1;

    if (txt.Length == 49)
    {
        if (txt[24] != "")
        {
            user_list usr = new user_list
            {
                email = (txt[24].Replace("'","")).Replace(" ",""),

                birthday = Convert.ToDateTime(txt[10].Replace("'","")), //THIS PART HAVE INCONSISTENT DATE FORMAT
                birthplace = (txt[9].Replace("'","")).Replace(" ",""),
                id_no = (txt[29].Replace("'", "")).Replace(" ", ""),
                id_valid_to = valid_to,
                modified_date = DateTime.Now,
                created_date = Convert.ToDateTime(txt[46].Replace("'", "")),
                language_pref = "ind",
                status_user = 1,
                user_type = "user",
                managed_by = "self",
                expected_salary = salary
            };

            imp.user_lists.InsertOnSubmit(usr);

         }
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception ("index : " + idx + " , total length : " + txt.Length);
    }            
}
```

Comment: try this one
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parse(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Try to use DateTime.Parse method. It parses "01-01-2014" and "2014-01-01" to equal DateTime

Comment: you can do at some extent, how may type of formats are available?

Comment: Does the data just vary between the two formats (yyyy-mm-dd and dd-mm-yyyy) that you mentioned? Or is it also sometimes in the mm-dd-yyyy format as well?

Comment: If it is in two formats mm-dd-yyyy and dd-mm-yyyy, then you judge the data only after number 12, and below less than 12, you should either consider it as month or day

Comment: @TanujMathur yes it's only (yyyy-mm-dd) or (dd-mm-yyyy)

Comment: In that case, you can use DateTime.TryParseExact with InvariantCulture, exactly as Mick suggested in his answer.

Comment: @TanujMathur thx, his approach worked!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works...

```
        string[] dates = new [] { "2014-01-01", "01-01-2014"};

        foreach (string d in dates)
        {
            DateTime parsed;
            if (DateTime.TryParseExact(d, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out parsed))
                Console.WriteLine("yyyy-MM-dd: {0}", parsed);
            else if (DateTime.TryParseExact(d, "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out parsed))
                Console.WriteLine("dd-MM-yyyy: {0}", parsed);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know the culture, you can try using [DateTime.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parse(v=vs.110).aspx#Parse1_Example) method.

So within that culture, as long as `01-01-2014` means either `dd-mm-yyyy` or `mm-dd-yyyy` consistently, you'll be fine.

Now since you mentioned your processing a multi-line data file, you probably should [DateTime.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1(v=vs.110).aspx). `TryParse` won't throw exception if it cannot parse a date, which in turn will not terminate your batch process. This allows you to log the failures and deal with them afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

Inconsistent date formats can be a pain in all scenarios. If you know that there is a specific set of cultures that you should try to use to convert (or if there is a way to determine the culture from another field), then I suggest you attempt to do something similar to the following:

```
DateTime convertedDate;
var convertSuccessful = DateTime.TryParse(date, new CultureInfo("en-US"), DateTimeStyles.None, out convertedDate);//YYYY-MM-DD
if (!convertSuccessful)
{
   DateTime.TryParse(date, new CultureInfo("en-GB"), DateTimeStyles.None, out convertedDate); // DD-MM-YYYY
}
```

**Note:** I think "en-US" culture is actually, "mm-dd-yyyy" so substitute another culture or build your own as necessary - this answer is more about the technique you can use if conversion fails with one culture without causing `FormatException` to be thrown.

Comment: thx, i tried it, but datetime.tryparse required 1 more parameter, voted up, mick solution worked.

Comment: Fixed the method parameters. And yes, `DateTime.TryParseExact()` would be the better choice then if those are the only formats you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that month and day fields are at consistent position in your input file. Then use  DateTime.Parse method.